# Computing the outer product of two vectors in Eigen c++

Tags: python, c++, eigen, eigen3

I have a piece of python code written using numpy that I'm trying to port over to C++ using the eigen library. I haven't really found anything suitable in the eigen library.

This is the python equivalent:

```
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
```

And What I've written using the Eigen Library is:

```
   Eigen::VectorXf u = Eigen::VectorXf::LinSpaced(100, 0, 2*PI);
   Eigen::VectorXf v = Eigen::VectorXf::LinSpaced(100, 0, PI);
   Eigen::MatrixXf x = u.cos().cross(v.cos());
   Eigen::MatrixXf y = u.sin().cross(v.sin());
   Eigen::MatrixXf z = Eigen::VectorXf::Ones(u.size()).cross(v);
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the cross function only works for vectors of size 3 as I get this error:

```
THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE
```

and I'm trying to compute for a much larger size. I found [this](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1037) from a thread a while back but it doesn't seem that this functionality was implemented. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You could check to see if there's anything in Eigen's "unsupported" header library. But it certainly does look like there was a flurry of interest a few years ago but it didn't go anywhere.

Comment: Why are you using the cross product? That is an entirely different thing from an outer product. For the record, an outer product would simply be ```a * b.transpose()``` (since ```Eigen::Vector``` is a column vector)

Comment: What @Homer512 said. Also, you should probably use `Eigen::VectorXf::LinSpaced` and `Eigen::VectorXf::Ones` (instead of `VectorXi`), and the second expression can also be written using `replicate`. And `u.cos()` will try to compute a matrix-cosine, you'll need to write `Eigen::VectorXf cos_u = Eigen::ArrayXf::LinSpaced(100, 0, 2*PI).cos()` (or `Eigen::VectorXf::LinSpaced(100, 0, 2*PI).array().cos()`). Finally, often it makes sense to avoid storing outer products explicitly (but that depends on what you do with it afterwards).

Comment: Another addendum, if you manage to make that work, but wonder why python gives more accurate results, it is likely because numpy uses double precision by default (I think). To get that with Eigen, use `VectorXd`, etc.

Comment: @chtz and Homer512, Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was missing. That did the trick.  As a followup, regarding `replicate`, how exactly, would you write that second expression? From a quick glance,my first thought went to doing something like `Eigen::VectorXd v = u.replicate(u.size(), 1) / 2;`

Comment: @MaskedAfrican When you replicate a Vector you will likely get (the shape of) a `MatrixXd`. And you may need to transpose the vector you want to replicate (depending on what result you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the same behavior as `np.outer(a, b)`, where `a` and `b` are both column vectors (i.e. `VectorXf` for instance) in Eigen it would simply be:

```cpp
a * b.transpose()
```

---

For info, [the thread you linked](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1037) has nothing to do with the outer product. Rather, it's about the "exterior product" (I know the two names are confusingly similar to each other); this is also known as wedge product and it is basically an extension of the cross product to N-dimensional vectors. According to this definition, the *exterior* product of N dimensional vectors is a skew-symmetric NxN matrix with i,j-th entry equal, up to the sign, `a[i]*b[j] - a[j]*b[i]`, while on the case of the *outer* product it would simply be `a[i]*b[j]`